# React not updating state on Child Component load

Tags: reactjs, state, react-state

So my interface is such that I have a MainScreen Component and then a UserList and People children component...when I click on the name in the list it runs a prop function from the Mainscreen and updated a prop which is sent to the People component I run a JS and update the prop I send to the People component...Person Details box in the graphic.....

[image]

So here is my People Component::

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faXmark } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faPlusCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'


function People(props){
    //LINE 8
    console.log('Start People')
    console.log(props.userDet)
    console.log(props.userDet.FirstName)
    const users = props.userDet
    console.log('Users vairable')
    console.log(users.FirstName) //returns true
    console.log(props.userDet.hasOwnProperty('FirstName'))
    const [fName,setfName] = useState(users.FirstName || 'n')
    const [lName,setlName] = useState(users.LastName || 'n')
    console.log('fName')
    console.log(fName)
    console.log(props.userDet.FirstName)
    //LINE 21

    const handleChange = e => {
        console.log('handle change running')
        if(e.target.name === 'fName'){
            setfName(e.target.value)
        }
        else{
            setlName(e.target.value)
        }
        
      }

    function formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumberString) {
        var cleaned = ('' + phoneNumberString).replace(/\D/g, '');
        var match = cleaned.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/);
        if (match) {
          return '(' + match[1] + ') ' + match[2] + '-' + match[3];
        }
        return null;
    }

    

    var phoness = props.userDet.phones;
    //console.log('phoness');
    //console.log(phoness);
    const onephone = phoness.map((phone,index) =>

    <div className={(index % 2) ? 'greyBg'+ " phonehold" : 'noBg'+ " phonehold"}  id={"phone_"+phone.phone_id} >
        <div>{phone.phone_type}</div>
        <div>{formatPhoneNumber.call(this, phone.phone_number)}</div>
        <div><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faXmark}/></div>
        </div>)
    
    
    return (<div id="peopledets">
        
        <div id="peoinfo">
            <div id="peonames">
            <div className="header">Person Details</div>
    <div className="holder"><div className="formlabel">First Name:</div><div><input onChange={handleChange} name="fName" type="text" value={fName} /></div></div>
    <div className="holder"><div className="formlabel">Last Name:</div><div><input onChange={handleChange} name="lName" type="text" value={lName} /></div></div>
    </div>
        <div id="peophones">
        <div className="header">Person Phones<span style={{marginLeft:'5px',fontSize:'.8em'}}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusCircle}/></span></div>
        
        {onephone}
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>)

}

export default People;
```

The returning Javascript shows that the prop is set but I can't get it to set the STATE because it is goint into an input field and needs to be updateable....no idea what is going on or why the state is not being updated.....

The JAVASCRIPT CONSOLE show the following

[image]

Comment: The value passed to `useState` is only processed once. Don't create state out of props

Comment: Add useEffect with dependences on `users` and setting state inside: `useEffect(() => { setfName(..); setlName(..)}, [users])` so that the component will update the state based on props.

Comment: @Konrad when you are passing them into input fields you can..

Comment: I would rather move handlers to the parents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add useEffect after line 21 like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setfName(users.FirstName);
   setlName(users.LastName);
}, [users.FirstName, users.LastName]);
```

Comment: ok this worked...thanks new to react here...I'm wondering why the array is needed at the end?

Comment: Array is a set of dependencies. When their values change the function is executed. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: much obliged..  need 15 charaters